# How to keep an element fixed scale and position in any zoom and offset of the browser on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, viewport

Is there a jquery plugin or other script that makes an element stay at the same scale and position (like fixed) on mobile browser, no matter where the page offset is or how much the viewport zoomed. e.g. create a tab-bar like footer that is fixed to the bottom of the screen, even if the web page is not mobile optimized (The viewport scale is not configured at the header section or in the css).
Thanks

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but can you not use fixed positioning in your CSS? Example: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-fixed-position.php

Comment: Support for fixed positioning in mobile browsers is really lacking. http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/